# Excel VBA to notify users via email when cells have changed

Tags: excel, vba

I have dabbled in VBA but I am certainly weak in it. My experience is mostly recording macros first, and modifying them with specifics as I find needs to sculpt them into something different.

I had an adjacent department come to me for excel help and they are looking to accomplish a couple things:
A spreadsheet that they use for project management has some columns that monitor the status of some activities. Whenever a user that saves the file AND changes any of the data in those columns (in this case lets say "in-progress" changes to "complete"), it would send an email out to a list of users.

Seems simple on its face and I have found VBA code that manages to accomplish some aspects of this but here is where I get confused.

1. If we are using VBA to tell these users (we can bake the email list into the VBA) that something has changed, how does the macro establish what the OLD and NEW snapshot even are? Does it run automatically upon file open to say "yes, here is the old value" then again upon file save to say "here is a new value, cell A5 has changed" ? An issue I have is that the desire is to make it seamless to the user, so it should not require the user click a button or run a macro. It should be seamless. I have seen some VBA out there run automatically upon file save but couldnt figure out how to integrate with what I had.
2. Even if we get a macro that can run and alert a list of contacts to a change in the file or  cells, how do we get the VBA code to indicate "this cell was changed from 'in-progress' to 'overdue' " for example. As opposed to "cell A5 , A6, A8 has changed" or something to that effect.

I have found a few pieces of code on other sites to fiddle with, but they didnt really go all the way.

This one does seem to work, but is only looking for a variance from a value that is hard coded into the code. For example, " <> 200 " But that is where I'd be needing to bake that snapshot logic in. Just have no idea how....I have tested and it does correctly open up outlook. I have even changed it to ".Send" and that also worked to just send the email out without needing to edit.

Then beyond that, the second conundrum is a more dynamic ability to say "cell c6 has changed FROM xx TO xx" and so forth. I would appreciate any guidance here.

```
Dim xRg As Range
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Set xRg = Intersect(Range("E6"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value <> 200 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 2"
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "TEST EMAIL"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "send by cell value test"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You could create a (hidden) sheet that shadows the data sheet. When the sheet is saved, run a sub that compares the 2 sheets, send differences per mail (if any) and then copy the data sheet to the shadow sheet.

Comment: @FunThomas that is certainly an option that I didnt even consider. Seems pretty simple. Im going to look into that method.